# bpy python: is it possible to get the selected collection?

Tags: python

for a script I am writing I need to know the collection that is currently selected in the outliner.
I have seen a solution where the ui is probed and it seemed very convoluted at the time and I was wondering if there might be a more elegant solution out there.

any tip and/or trick would be greatly appreciated.

thx,
S

Comment: Take a look at this repository, it has a function that could help you, get_active_collection () https://github.com/curtisjamesholt/EasyBPY/blob/master/easybpy.py

Comment: As this is a new account, I cannot reply to answers, but thank you Richard Collao, that was exactly what I was looking for !  The great thing of se is that is it a welcoming community where you can ask your questions, the downside is maybe that when you get the answer, you feel slightly silly that it was under your nose the entire time.